# Html justify a word in a div

Tags: html, css

i need to justify 3 menu-words in a columns: lenght of words are different but i need them occupy 100% of the vertical div (like justify). 
i've tried using a justified text-align as well as using a paragraph for every word and setting a different letter-spacing of every one but without any result. 
I hope to well explained the problem and the solution i've tried.
Thank's

HTML:

```
<div class="container vert" id="left">
 <div class="container" id="menu">
 <a href=""><p class="menuitem" id="works">works</p> </a>  <br>
 <a href=""> <p class="menuitem" id="contacts">contacts </p> </a> <br>
 <a href=""> <p class="menuitem" id="share">share </p> </a> <br>
 </div>`
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left {
float: left;
border: 1px solid red;
width: 20%;
opacity: 0.7;
}


#menu {
word-wrap: break-word;
left: auto;
height: auto;
font-family: 'PT Sans', 'sans-serif';
letter-spacing: 16px;
font-size: 18pt;
color: #4D4D4D;
text-align: center;
}

.menuitem{
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This is a programming Q&A. Programming questions often work best with code.

Comment: have any link to jsfiddle?

Comment: no js used till now. and since i don't know js i prefer do not copy and paste pieces of code. is possible to fix the problem only using html and css?

Comment: i've found an example i can use to better explain: http://jsfiddle.net/HuFZL/103/ i want the text "Hello, world!" occupy all the p space, from the left to the right, leaving needed space between letters

Answer (score -1):

You have to get back the size of your menu. Somethink like

```
var widthMenu1 = $('#idMenu1').width();
```

And then adjuste the size of the text in function of the width you get,

```
$('#idMenu1Label').attr('font-size', widthMenu1/10);
```

10 is an exemple. And then you can aproove this, with another function